# create a bash script that will grep from a file

Tags: bash, grep

I would like to create a bash script that reads a file and then those lines in the file are used as a search string to grep my computer. Also, the strings are embedded within another search string. Normally, I would run the following:

`grep -R -oE ".{0,5}findme\(.{0,40}"`

which would look for the 5 characters before and 40 characters after the phrase findme(

The following code is what I was thinking but I get the error `grep: parentheses not balanced`

```
input="../list.txt"
while IFS= read -r line
do
  grep -R -oE ".{0,5}{$line}/(.{0,40}"  
  echo "$line"
done < "$input"
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: When you get `parentheses not balanced`, read your code. How many left and right parentheses do you have? Hint: Use non-interpolating `'` ... `'`

Comment: Replace `grep -R -oE` with `echo`. You'll probably figure it out. Use a one line `list.txt` to make debugging easier.

Comment: Is the `/` supposed to be a backslash?

Comment: @rpthomps: You are trying to reinvent the wheel. Have a look at the `--file` option of `grep`.  It seems that this is doing exactly what you need - you don't have to read your file line by line.

Comment: @Shawn ...uh...yes. That's embarrassing. Thanks. Ted, Jeff and User, thanks for your time and your responses. I am going to look into echo and file too